# Set active layer for created objects

Tags: modeling, 3d-view, layers

I noticed when I add objects to my scene they will be created in the layer 3. It isnt like that from the beginning but it suddenly starts to place new objects into the third layer after some time working.

I dont have any problem with that since I just can use the third layer as "main" layer. My question is if there is a possibility to set an active layer where new objects get placed into? So that I have control over the objects placements in layers from the beginning. For example when I know I place a lot of "unnecessary" stuff I choose one of the last layers and dont have to manually drop them into that layer after i created them.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uncheck and check on your "active" layer with <kbd>Shift</kbd>.

Objects adds on last selected layer, so if you turn off and on the layer, it will be  "active"

Also, you can read about it: [Active Layer Indicator](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36952/active-layer-indicator)

Comment: Yeah thanks that did it. Now I know why it suddenly started to use the 3rd layer as active layer.. because I always used shift to select more layers to see all objects.. 
thanks a lot. :D

Answer (score 2):

Before you add an object, make to the layer you want it to be at as the "Active Layer".

You can use the numbers on the keyboard (not in the numpad) to select the active layer choosing from <kbd>1</kbd> to <kbd>0</kbd>.  To select layers 11 through 20 use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Number</kbd>.

To activate more than one layer you can use <kbd>Shift</kbd>.
You can have multiple layers visible but only one of them will be the **Active** one, usually the last one that was selected.

More about layers on the [Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/properties/relations/layers.html?highlight=active)